# How to keep fragments state like Instagram in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, instagram, bottomnavigationview

I need to implement the UI of my app, like the Instagram one. I need to switch from different fragments, with the usage of the bottom navigation view, but I need to keep state of the fragments, like I left them. How Can I achieve this?

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    item.setChecked(true);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_formation:
            if (homeFragment == null) {
                homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
            }
            displayFragment(homeFragment);
            break;
        case R.id.action_result:
            if (introResultFragment == null) {
                introResultFragment = new IntroResultFragment();
            }
            displayFragment(introResultFragment);
            break;

        case R.id.action_market:
            displayFragment(new MarketFragment());
            break;
    }
    return false;
}


public void displayFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment.getClass().toString());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Hey, check this implementation, it should suit your needs - https://medium.com/@smihajlovskih/create-instagram-like-backstack-4711600c5bff

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time but I want to offer my open source library in github which implements the same UX of Youtube and Instagram:
https://github.com/ZachBublil/ZNavigator

You got to add this dependency to your gradle:

```
compile 'com.zach.znavigator:znavigator:1.0.0'
```

The only thing you have to do is to pass the list of fragments you want to be in the BottomNavigationView:

```
  public class SampleActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        navigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Fragment> rootFragments = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        rootFragments.put(R.id.tab1, new FirstTab());
        rootFragments.put(R.id.tab2,new SecondTab());
        rootFragments.put(R.id.tab3, new ThirdTab());
        init(rootFragments, R.id.container);

        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void tabChanged(int id) {
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(id).setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

If you want to open a new fragment as inner screen in one of the tabs you can do it by using ZNavigation class in the tab fragment:

```
ZNavigation.openChildFragment(getFragmentManager(),new ChildFragment());
```

Answer (score 0):

just remember the active fragment, and use userVisiableHint to get active status in each fragment.

```
private Fragment currentFragment; // need to be init

private void switch2Fragment(Fragment target){
    getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    if(target.isAdded){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(currentFragment).show(target).commit();
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(currentFragment).add(R.id.xxx, target).commit();
    }
    currentFragment.setUserVisibleHint(false);
    currentFragment = target;
    target.setUserVisibleHint(true);
}

private boolean isFragmentActive(Fragment target){
    return target.getUserVisibleHint();
}
```